# how to set the status of a component to unapproved in Tridion 2013

Tags: 2013, workflow

I have a workflow requirement where i need to set the status of new component/page to unapproved .

I can see component.ApprovalStatus is read only property.

one way is that i can attach a bundle workflow to schema as well which will set the status to unapproved each time component/page is edited but i have used generic component to create different pages.  Can i utilize task process workflow here.

Is there any other way to achieve this.

Comment: Can you set the status in the Workflow Process Definition in Visio for a given Activity? You could use single-item workflow but be careful with mixing it with Bundles since both workflow processes will lock items (i.e. a Component can't be in both Bundle *and* single-item Workflow at the same time).

Comment: Jitender - did you resolve this challenge? If so, how?

Comment: Dylan - If I remember correctly then I was trying to set the status of newly created component/pages to unapproved instead of unassigned. As newly created component/pages were unassigned, these can directly be published by skipping minimum approval check on publication target. My bundle workflow was not able to control this scenario.We raised this with Tridion also and they said they will provide a fix for this. Later we stopped the development for some other project reason . So we didn't get any solution for this.

Answer (score 2):

Since this question there's been a hotfix (available on tridionworld - CM_2013.1.0.88203). This is also described [here](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/8054/old-workflow-items-set-to-unapproved) and [here](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/13327/tridion-2013-workflow-minimal-approval-status).

Essentially now achieved through event system code (example [here](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/13481/workflow-editing-content-outside-of-an-active-workflow-bundle)).

Comment: This is now open in Web 8 - Approval status can be changed at any time, even outside of workflow, through the API