# Tridion 2013 Workflow - Minimal Approval Status

Tags: 2013, workflow, 2013-sp1

I am trying to implement workflow for component content where specific group of user can approve that or not.
The Minimum Approval status is set up on the Publication Target which corresponds to the last approval status in workflow.
When component finishes the workflow there is status "Ready for Live" (on workflow tab of component) and that status is set as Minimal Approval Status on Publication Target "Live".

During publishing, "Live" Target is available not matter in which status component is.

My assumption was that "Live" Target will be available only if component has "Ready for Live" status or "Undefined".

My assumption was that if component is in workflow, the status should be "Unapproved" when it is in some step in workflow before the real approval status is assigned, but in my case it is "Undefined"

How it is possible to have that status instead of "Unapproved"?

If component is added on the page, should page be also available for publishing if all components added on that page have one of these statuses "Ready for Life" or "Undefined"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although the Live Target Type is shown in the publishing dialogue, if you try to publish to it you should find that the Publisher fails the job with an error message stating that the component does not meet the minimum approval status. This is (partly) because your templates may try to render a component which is not placed directly on your page (maybe via a component link) and the job still needs to fail. Also, you may have functionality in your templating to not publish the component (perhaps you filter it out somehow), in which case it would be perfectly fine to publish it to Live.

The approval status is set to whatever you configure as the approval status for the individual activities in your workflow design. If you set the approval status for the first activity as 'Unapproved' then after that activity has been finished then the components will have that status. The default status *should* be Unapproved, according to the online documentation's [Workflow and the Event System](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-B12C3981-CC52-4CAD-87B5-800185541480) topic. There's also [hotfix 88203](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-6393DB2B-A141-4E48-9A78-010B7F7381F8), included with Hotfix Rollup 1, which changes this behaviour for components that are no longer directly configured for workflow which may be having an effect.

Comment: Ok, but why item in my workflow has status "Undefined" instead of "Unaproved"?

Comment: I'm getting to that... Updating my answer as I go :)

Comment: Thank you on answer. In Visio every activity has its own approval status.
"Undefined" status is when some item is in some Activity and pending finishing. Take a look on the following link. https://www.dropbox.com/s/vjxa521gt91yuzp/Capture.PNG?dl=0

Comment: OK. That's what the Workflow Process Instance is showing you, but what is the actual approval status of the component(s) if you open it/them?

Comment: Please see scenario:
Minimal approval status setup on Publication Target "Live" is "Ready for Live".
Component is in workflow and has some other approval status.
Component is added to some page. Page is triggered for publishing. Page is published successfully. 

How it is possible to publish page where that component is added?

Is this related to 
- Target language set on the Publication Target? ("REL" in this case)
- the output of the page? (DXA and static publishing)

Should there be some custom code to check if the component approval status does not match to the minimal approval status?

Comment: No custom code is necessary to enforce minimal approval statuses. This is checked when the component data is loaded through the TOM.Net API. As explained, a page template could choose to not render a particular ComponentPresentation via some conditional logic and therefore the page would still be publishable even if the component itself did not meet the minimum approval status. Similarly, a component template could load data from a linked component and that also will be checked for approval.

Comment: I just found this in SDL Documentation: If an item achieves a Workflow status known as minimum approval status for a destination, you can publish it to that destination. If the item is in Workflow and does not meet the minimum approval status, the Content Manager publishes the last checked-in version of the item (if it exists and if it does have a minimum approval status that allows it to be published). 

So, If page should have failed status custom code should be written

Comment: I still maintain that no custom code is necessary, because it should be perfectly valid to publish the page with a prior, fully approved, version

Comment: Hey David, just finished testing, I agree with you. There is no need custom code to prevent publishing, since it will be published last approval version of content. It can be developed only if client wants to have error. But this approach is enough. Thanks for all your help

Answer (score 1):

> My assumption was that if component is in workflow, the status should
>   be "Unapproved" when it is in some step in workflow before the real
>   approval status is assigned, but in my case it is "Undefined"

Components current Approval Status in the workflow is the Approval Status of the component in the last **finished** activity.

The "Undefined" status you are seeing with the last activity (that is still not finished) is not the current Approval Status of the component, it's just saying it's still not known.

You can check the current Approval Status of the component in Tridion_cm database by querying ITEMS table with the component you are using in the workflow. There is a column there called APPROVAL_STATUS_ID...

Comment: I wrote code which shows current approval status of component, which as you defined it is status of last finished activity.
If component is in workflow and if I run the code, I got the good value.
Thanks

Comment: @user513 - did you use core service code for this? is it possible to share?

Comment: no, for checking current status of component you can use component.ApprovalStatus.Id.ToString()